# Is there a library for AJAX?

Tags: ajax

I want to learn AJAX from scratch on my own. My seniors have told me that AJAX requires a library, such as jQuery.

I have searched on Google and various forums, but I could not find anything like a library. I am really very confused; please tell me if there is such a thing as a library for AJAX?

Comment: did you mention the famous jQuery ? jQuery is an AJAX library. However, seeking for library is off-topic in SO

Comment: AJAX is a technology term , asynchronous javascript and xml but now xml is no more, everyone use json in place of xml.

Comment: It seems to me that this question is not precisely asking for a library recommendation per se; I'd read it as: "Is it possible to do AJAX stuff *without* using a library, and (if not) which libraries would I need to use?" As I pointed out in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28936951/4200092), you *don't* need a library to do AJAX stuff, but I'd imagine that a lot of people would overlook `XMLHttpRequest` when searching for AJAX-related stuff because it doesn't explicitly include the phrase "AJAX" in its name (jQuery, on the other hand, *does* explicitly refer to AJAX requests as "AJAX".)

Comment: Have to chime in for @GoBusto here, this is actually a good question for the site if you don't match the word library to close and read the question.

Comment: @GoBusto  You got it right.. That's my actually point of asking this question. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For pure Javascript, use [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) for AJAX requests. See [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) for instructions on how to use it.

If you're using jQuery, see the jQuery [`AJAX`](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) documentation instead.

Comment: It means there no other way of using AJAX. Right?

Comment: More or less. `XMLHttpRequest` is the "built in" way to do AJAX using Javascript, and third-party libraries (such a jQuery) are basically just wrappers around that; they're doing the same thing internally, but present a different external API for you to use.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a library that is called *AJAX Control Tool Kit* for developers

Comment: But as far as i know, it is relating to asp.net